# jQuery Ajax post for newbie

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

First let me say I'm new to Ajax. I've been reading articles from jquery.com and some tutorials but I didn't figured it out yet how this works on what I'm trying to achieve.

I am trying to get the weather for a searched city using Google's Weather API XML, **without page refresh.**

I managed to retrieve the Weather XML and parse the data but everytime I search for a different place, the page reloads since my weather widget is under a tab.

This is what I have in my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // FOR THE TAB
    $('.tab_btn').live('click', function (e) {
        $('.tab_content').fadeIn();
    });


    $(".submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url:"weather.php", 
        datatype: "text",
        aysnc:false,
        success:function(result){
        $(".wedata").html(result);
        }});
    });

});
</script>
<style>.tab_content{display:none;}</style>
</head><body>
<input type="button" value="Show Content" class="tab_btn">
<div class="tab_content">
        <h2>Weather</h2>
    <form id="searchform" onKeyPress="return submitenter(this,event)" method="get"/>
    <input type="search" placeholder="City" name="city">
    <input  type="hidden" placeholder="Language" name="lang">
    <input type="submit" value="search" class="submit" style="width:100px">
    </form>
    <div id="weather" class="wedata">




    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the actual demo I'm working on: http://downloadlive.org.

Now, if I add `action="weather.php"` on the search form I get the results, but I get redirected to weather.php which is logical. Without the `action="weather.php"`, everytime I search my index which I'm on, adds up `/?city=CITY+NAME` which shouldn't. This should be added to weather.php, get the results and then retrieve them back into my index, if that makes sense?

This is my php code for weather.php: http://pastebin.com/aidXCeQg

which can be viewed here: http://downloadlive.org/weather.php

Can someone please help me out with this please?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `return false`; from the `click` event handler. This will prevent the default action from occuring - in this case, submitting the form. Also, remove the `async: false` setting. You almost never want synchronous ajax requests.

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url:"weather.php", 
        datatype: "text",
        success: function(result){
            $(".wedata").html(result);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Alternately you can pass a parameter name to the callback and then use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to accomplish the same result as above:

```
$(".submit").click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url:"weather.php", 
        datatype: "text",
        success: function(result){
            $(".wedata").html(result);
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

You need to send the form data with the `POST`. It's super-easy to do this using [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize).

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url:"weather.php",
        data: $(this.form).serialize(),
        datatype: "text",
        success: function(result){
            $(".wedata").html(result);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Once you get the code functional (that is, correct/working) you should post it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com to get advice on how to improve it.

Comment: Thanks alot sir. This is what I was looking for somehow. The search is working perfectly, but once I search one time, I cant search again for another city. I updated http://downloadlive.org. Is there anything simple that's missing?

Comment: By the way, I've noticed that e.preventDefault(); doesnt work?

Comment: Did you make sure to name the callback's parameter `e`?

Comment: Missed that. Hm it seems though it's not what I was looking for. This just gets what's on weather.php, whatever the search term is. It's like I'm loading weather.php

Comment: Ah yes, you need to pass the search for data to the post as well. See my edit.

Comment: There should be something else with my php because it seems that I still get same results. Thanks for your time by the way.

Comment: Found it! The type has to be 'get'.